# .net image selection with mouse like desktop selection on windows

Tags: .net, image, c++-cli, picturebox

I want to select a part of an image on picturebox. I can take the coordinates of the mouse up and down but at the same time I want to show a selection box according to the ouse movement. It is like desktop selection on windows. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx

**However**, If you want to handle rendering of the background by yourself, you would use the `VisualStyleRenderer` class.

The [`VisualStyleElemnt.ListView.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.listview.item.aspx) class has all of the states that you could render:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.listview.item.aspx